# Pressing UIButton results in Unrecognized Selector error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, selector

I have a button in my `UIView` that is created like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
                                                      target:self       
                                                      action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
[editButton release];
```

And this is the action method:

```
-(void) toggleEdit:(id)sender
{
}
```

but I get this error

> 2011-09-02 15:27:13.362 blubb[15006:207] -[DatabaseSelectionViewController toggleEdit]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a29d80
>   2011-09-02 15:27:13.365 blubb[15006:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DatabaseSelectionViewController toggleEdit]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a29d80'

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
@selector(toggleEdit)
```

to

```
@selector(toggleEdit:)
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct name for your selector is

```
@selector(toggleEdit:)
```

Without the **:** it would look for a method with this signature:

```
-(void) toggleEdit  // No parameters
{
}
```

When you actually have declared:

```
-(void) toggleEdit:(id)sender
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling across this, you can also receive those *"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x..."* errors when you no longer own something and the statement is pointing to some junk address in memory.

Comment: Although in this specific case, as others have stated, the @selector was missing the colon.

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
-(IBAction) toggleEdit:(id)sender {}
```

and

```
@selector(toggleEdit:)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're trying to use takes an argument, which means that it has a colon in its name -- the colon is actually *part of* the name. You need to include that colon when you get the selector:

```
@selector(toggleEdit:)
```

Refer to the [Message Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6) section of The Objective-C Programming Language:

> A selector name includes all the parts of the name, including the colons, so the selector in the preceding example is named `setOriginX:y:`. It has two colons, because it takes two parameters. The selector name does not, however, include anything else, such as return type or parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard. Sometimes it helps to remove the button from the storyboard, and put a new button, and make the necessary connections.